# Selenium IE can't find an element by XPath with "invalid selector" error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, ie

I'm getting strange error using Selenium WebDriver with IE (version 11). Here log of Selenium:

```
D 2021-06-02 16:33:46:334 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\elementfinder.cpp(60) Using FindElement atom to locate element having xpath = //*[@data-at-selector='formsKisConnectSignUpDialog']//*[@id='EMail']
I 2021-06-02 16:33:46:334 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\browser.cpp(142) No child frame focus. Focus is on top-level frame
D 2021-06-02 16:33:46:560 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\variantutilities.cpp(105) Result type is JScriptTypeInfo
D 2021-06-02 16:33:46:571 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\variantutilities.cpp(105) Result type is JScriptTypeInfo
D 2021-06-02 16:33:46:589 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\variantutilities.cpp(105) Result type is JScriptTypeInfo
W 2021-06-02 16:33:46:919 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\webdriver-server\response.cc(98) Error response has status code 32 and message 'Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@data-at-selector='formsKisConnectSignUpDialog']//*[@id='EMail'] because of the following error:
[object Error]' message
D 2021-06-02 16:33:46:923 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\iecommandexecutor.cpp(786) Setting serialized response to {
    "value" : 
    {
        "data" : null,
        "error" : "invalid selector",
        "message" : "Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@data-at-selector='formsKisConnectSignUpDialog']//*[@id='EMail'] because of the following error:\n[object Error]",
        "stacktrace" : ""
    }
}
```

Obviously the selector is good, nothing wrong with the specified XPath. The error occurs only with IE.

I'm trying to get element with just `RemoteWebDriver.FindElement` with `By.XPath` in C#.

Comment: please add the code that throws this error

Comment: @PDHide added info about how I get an element. Code actually won't add additional info. I just use `FindElement`.

Comment: /*[@data-at-selector='formsKisConnectSignUpDialog']//*[@id='EMail'] is this a valid input ,if you try this on developer console?

Comment: @Maxim Check xpath for IE. Seems xpath is not valid for IE.

Comment: Try this, open the browser press F12, then select console, us then try to use QuerySelector using the same XPath, if the browser can't find it then there's either something wrong with the XPATH, or the element is not addressible.